# Find the value of k if the roots of an equation differ by 2.

Tags: roots

I need some help, Im trying to solve the below but to no avail, would appreciate your guidance :)

Find the value of $k$ if the roots of 
$$3x^2+5x-k=0,$$
differ by two.

Comment: Write down the two roots in terms of $k$ then equate the absolute value of the difference to $2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $r $ and $r+2$ be the roots.

Their sum is $$r+ (r+2)=\frac{-5}{3}$$

thus

$$r=\frac {-11}{6}. $$

Their product is

$$r (r+2)=\frac {-k}{3}.$$

thus
$$k=\frac{11}{12} $$

the roots are
$-\frac {11}{6} $ and
$\frac 1 6$

Answer (score 2):

Outline:

Let the roots be $u,v$.

Use Vieta's formulas to find $u+v$ and $uv$.

Then use the identity $(u-v)^2 = (u+v)^2 - 4uv$.

Once you have the value of $(u-v)^2$ in terms of $k$, set it to $4$ and solve for $k$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the polynomial factors as $(3x+a)(x+b)$.  Then the roots are $a/3$ and $b$, which have to differ by two.  If you multiply $(3x+a)(x+b)$ out and compare it to the original polynomial, you should have enough relationships to extract the answer.

Answer (score 0):

From the quadratic formula, we know that if the equation $ax^2+bx+c=0$ has two distinct real roots, then their difference is $2\sqrt{b^2-4ac}$. Plugging in the values from your equation, this means that $2\sqrt{25+12k}=2$. Solve for $k$.